# Using same directory declaration for multiple Vhosts

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost, httpd.conf

Is there a method for declaring name based virtual hosts, but sharing the same directory declarations?  So for example, the Directory section in both of these Vhosts is the same, so is there a method to only declare it once, and have it used by both Vhosts?  Same for the Error log section.  Is there a method for declaring the error log only once? (Possibly inside the Directory?)

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName email.123456.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/mail
        <Directory /var/www/mail>
                Options FollowSymLinks
                DirectoryIndex index.php
                AllowOverride All
                Order Allow,Deny
                Allow from All
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/mail/error.log
        LogLevel warn
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/mail/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerName email.123456.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/mail
        <Directory /var/www/mail>
                Options FollowSymLinks
                DirectoryIndex index.php
                AllowOverride All
                Order Allow,Deny
                Allow from All
        </Directory>
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/mail/error.log
        LogLevel warn
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/mail/access.log combined

        SSLEngine on

        SSLCertificateFile    /var/certs/123456/123456.com.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /var/certs/123456/123456.key
        SSLCertificateChainFile /var/certs/123456/sf_bundle.crt

        <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
                SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
        </FilesMatch>
        BrowserMatch "MSIE [2-6]" nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0
        BrowserMatch MSIE [17-9] ssl-unclean-shutdown
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it were me, I'd store the shared configurations in "fragment" .conf files and use the Include directive in each VirtualHost or other place that shares the configurations within those fragments.  i.e.

```
Include conf-fragments/error-log.conf
Include conf-fragments/Directory-mail.conf
```

Comment: I was wanting to keep them in the same file, but I can see some advantages (in reducing redundancy mainly), so I will give this a try.  Thanks!